# Forum Post urls with Pathauto

Tags: path-aliases, nodes

I'm using Drupal (v7.21) with Pathauto and Advanced Forum and would like the paths to be formatted like:

```
domain.com/forum
domain.com/forum/the_topic_name
domain.com/forum/the_topic_name/the_post_name
```

Under Forum Paths 'Pattern for forums and forum containers' is set as:

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]
```

And under Content Paths I've set 'Pattern for all Forum topic paths' as:

```
[node:taxonomy_forums]/[node:title]
```

This is working except for the Posts which are missing the /forum/ part:

```
domain.com/the_topic_name/the_post_name
```

I could manually get this to work by setting the 'Pattern for all Forum topic paths' as:

```
forum/[node:taxonomy_forums]/[node:title]
```

But I'd rather have it set using a pattern if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can just add **forum/** to the beginning of 'Pattern for forums and forum containers' & 'Pattern for all Forum topic paths'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add pattern like `[node:content-type]` or `[node:content-type:name]`. So the actual pattern will be `[node:content-type]/[node:taxonomy_forums]/[node:title]`

Comment: [node:content-type] and [node:content-type:name] give: '/forum-topic/'

Comment: try `[node:content-type:machine-name]` pattern

Answer (score 0):

From the answer by monymirza it works as:

```
set Pattern for all Forum topic paths as
[node:content-type:machine-name]/[node:taxonomy_forums]/[node:title]
```

It also works with:

```
set Pattern for all Forum topic paths as
[node:taxonomy-forums:vocabulary]/[node:taxonomy-forums:name]/[node:title]
```

But if you have a Topic within sub Forums/Containers it won't show them in the urls for Topics. So from more research I found that you can get Topics to show the correct path with:

```
set Pattern for all Forum topic paths as
[node:taxonomy-forums:vocabulary]/[node:taxonomy-forums:parent]/[node:taxonomy-forums:name]/[node:title]
```

You then need to set the pattern for the Forum/Container paths as they are separate:

```
set Pattern for forums and forum containers as
[term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:name]/[term:name]
```

For both of these if you have multiple levels of sub categories you can keep extending this with 'parent:parent' like:

```
set Pattern for forums and forum containers as
[term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:parent:name]/[term:parent:name]/[term:name]
```

If I've missed anything please let me know as I'm very new to Drupal.